# group scheme structure on a flat $S$-scheme with fibres Abelian varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A \to S$ be a flat morphism of schemes such that $A \otimes_S k(s)$ is an Abelian variety for every $s \in S$. Is it true then that $A$ is an Abelian S-scheme?

update: to lift the obstruction when the morphism doesn't have a section, let me rephrase the question: is it true that there exists a Zariski dense subset $U$ and a finite base change $U' \to U$ so that $A \times_S U$ is an Abelian $U$-scheme?

Comment: If it is, then the map must have a section $S\to A$ corresponding to the identity and in general, it may not.

Comment: ok, and suppose I am willing to restrict to an open of $S$ and perform a finite base change?